# Remove duplicate rows based on presence of other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, and am trying to remove any rows with blank `EOB` codes where multiple `EOB` codes already exist for that `Account Number`. So, for example, we have this "407" `Account Number` contributing three rows. I'd like the row with the missing `EOB` code to be removed, but the remaining two lines (with EOB codes 7730 and 3033) to stay.

[image]

However, the complexity here (at least for me) is that other `Account Number` never had an `EOB` code. Like the accounts ending in "2300" and "6200" below. In these specific cases, these types of accounts should *remain* in the dataframe.

[image]

Here's a small portion of this dataset:

```
data = {'Account Number': ['407','407','407','4901','4901','4901','4901','4901','6902','6902','6902','6902','8700','6900','2300','6200','2400','2400','3200','3200','3200','3200','3200','3200','3400','2200','3300','7701','7701','7701','7701','7701','7701','3100','401','401','401','6600','6600','6600','6600'],
     'Payer':['BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS','BCBS'],
     'Remit Type':['IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Paid','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Denied','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid','IP Paid'],
     'EOB':['','7730','3033','5001','','9932','3035','3038','9015','5000','','9932','','','','','','','','3035','829','9932','2635','5002','','','','851','','852','9932','818','9015','','','2628','3035','5003','','3035','9932'],
     'Date':['Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10','Mar 10'],
     'Status':['INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED', 'INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID','INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Account Number','Payer','Remit Type','EOB','Date','Status'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to identify the indexes to drop with the following conditions:

- Account Number has at least one row with a non empty EOB
- EOB is the empty string

It could be:

1. Find the relevant account numbers:

   ```
   x = df[df.EOB != ''].groupby('Account Number').count()[[]]
   ```
2. Drop the rows:

   ```
   df.drop(df.merge(x, left_on='Account Number', right_index=True).query("EOB==''").index,
           inplace=True)
   ```

Starting with the sample, it gives:

```
    Account Number Payer Remit Type   EOB    Date                      Status
1              407  BCBS  IP Denied  7730  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
2              407  BCBS  IP Denied  3033  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
3             4901  BCBS    IP Paid  5001  Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
5             4901  BCBS    IP Paid  9932  Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
6             4901  BCBS    IP Paid  3035  Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
7             4901  BCBS    IP Paid  3038  Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
8             6902  BCBS  IP Denied  9015  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
9             6902  BCBS  IP Denied  5000  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
11            6902  BCBS  IP Denied  9932  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
12            8700  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
13            6900  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
14            2300  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
15            6200  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
16            2400  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
17            2400  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
19            3200  BCBS    IP Paid  3035  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
20            3200  BCBS    IP Paid   829  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
21            3200  BCBS    IP Paid  9932  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
22            3200  BCBS    IP Paid  2635  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
23            3200  BCBS    IP Paid  5002  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
24            3400  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
25            2200  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
26            3300  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
27            7701  BCBS  IP Denied   851  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
29            7701  BCBS  IP Denied   852  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
30            7701  BCBS  IP Denied  9932  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
31            7701  BCBS  IP Denied   818  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
32            7701  BCBS  IP Denied  9015  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
33            3100  BCBS    IP Paid        Mar 10  INPATIENT CLAIMS SUSPENDED
35            0401  BCBS  IP Denied  2628  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
36            0401  BCBS  IP Denied  3035  Mar 10     INPATIENT CLAIMS DENIED
37            6600  BCBS    IP Paid  5003  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
39            6600  BCBS    IP Paid  3035  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
40            6600  BCBS    IP Paid  9932  Mar 10       INPATIENT CLAIMS PAID
```

Comment: Serge, this is really nice. I like the way you explained your steps and showed the output as well. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Serge, can you please accept my edit? These account numbers should not be displayed publicly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to check if all the `EOB` associated to an account is empty or not. Then you can combine these with non-empty `EOB`:

```
all_empty = df['EOB'].eq('').groupby(df['Account Number']).transform('all')

df[all_empty | df['EOB'].ne('')]
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, personally, I would suggest refraining from using `''` empty string in `pandas`. Use `np.nan` instead:

```
import numpy as np

df['EOB'] = df['EOB'].replace('', np.nan)
```

Then define a helper function to only `dropna` when there is more than 1 row and apply it on the `groupby` items based on `Account Number`

```
def dropna_if_not_the_only_row(df):
    if df.shape[0] == 1:
        return df
    else:
        return df.dropna()

df.groupby('Account Number').apply(lambda x : dropna_if_not_the_only_row(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
```